# How to calculate $\int \frac{dx}{\cos(x) + \sin(x)} $?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I did it by the method of integration by parts, with

$$
u=\frac{dx}{\cos(x) + \sin(x)},\quad dv=dx$$

so
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\cos(x) + \sin(x)} = 
\frac{x}{\cos(x)+\sin(x)}
- \int \frac{x(\sin(x)-\cos(x))}{(\cos(x) 
+ \sin(x))^{2}} 
$$
Where,
$$\int \frac{x(\sin(x)-\cos(x))}{(\cos(x) + \sin(x))^{2}}\;dx
= \int \frac{x \sin(x)}{1+2\sin(x)\cos(x)}dx - \int \frac{x \cos(x)}{1+2\sin(x)\cos(x)}dx ,
$$
I have not managed to solve those two integrals that were expressed, really appreciate if you can help me.

Comment: What are you trying to prove?

Comment: I think you're asking how to *evaluate* that integral.

Comment: Yes, i type wront, i wantt to say how evaluate, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int \frac{dx}{\cos(x) + \sin(x)} $$
$$=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt2\left(\sin (x)\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos(x) \right)} $$
$$=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt2\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)} $$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt2}\int \csc \left(x+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)\ d\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4} \right) $$
Using formula: $\int\csc\theta d\theta=\ln\left|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|$,
$$=\frac1{\sqrt2}\ln\left|\tan\left(\frac{x+\frac{\pi}{4}}{2}\right)\right|+C$$
$$=\frac1{\sqrt2}\ln\left|\tan\left(\frac x2+\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\right|+C$$

Answer (score 5):

Use$$\int\frac{dx}{\cos x+\sin x}=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sec(x-\pi/4)dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln|\sec(x-\pi/4)+\tan(x-\pi/4)|+C.$$

Comment: How you know that identity please?

Comment: You use $\sin(x)= \cos (x- \frac{\pi}{2})$ right?

Comment: Oh i see!!! Thank you

Comment: $$\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\cos{x}+\sin{x})$$

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to compute the antiderivative, but integration by parts is not one of them.

One method that was used was to recall the angle addition identity $$\cos (x - \theta) = \cos x \cos \theta + \sin x \sin \theta,$$ and letting $\theta = \pi/4$ gives $$\cos \left(x - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\cos x + \sin x}{\sqrt{2}},$$ from which it follows that $$\frac{1}{\sin x + \cos x} = \sqrt{2} \sec \left( x - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$ as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{dx}{\cos(x) + \sin(x)}=\int \frac{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x) -\sin^2(x)}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)}dx-\int \frac{\sin(x)-\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{\cos(x)}{1-2 \sin^2(x)}dx+\int \frac{\sin(x)}{1-2\cos^2(x)}dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\sin(x)\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\cos(x)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Make the substitution $$t=\tan(\frac x2)$$with
$$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\;\;,\;\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\;\;dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$$

the integral becomes
$$-2\int \frac{dt}{t^2-2t-1}=$$
$$\frac 12\int (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{(t-1+\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{t-1-\sqrt{2}})dt$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx=\int\frac{1}
{a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)}dx$
where $a=b=1$
We put $ a=r\sin(y), b=r\cos(y) ,r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}, y=\tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{b})$
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{1}{a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)}dx=\int\frac{dx}{r\sin(y)\sin(x)+r\cos(y)\cos(x)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\int\frac{dx}{\cos(x+y)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\int\frac{\sec(x+y)(\sec(x+y)+\tan(x+y))}{\sec(x+y)+\tan(x+y)}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\log(\sec(x+y)+\tan(x+y))\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\log(\frac{1}{\cos(x+\tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{b})}+\frac{\sin(x+\tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{b}))}{\cos(x+\tan^{-1})(\frac{a}{b}))})\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\log(\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(x+\tan^{-1}(\frac{a}{b}))}{a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)})
\end{align*}
we put $ a=1, b=1$
$\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log(\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\tan^{-1}(1))}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)})$

Comment: it's ok now. well done

Comment: how did you get $sin(x+\tan^{-1}(1))$ in your answer? is it $\pi/4$?

Comment: Yes Doesn't matter to write

Comment: I am confuse $\cos (x+y)= \cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y$ right? But. You change with $+$

Comment: @weymar andres Yes thanks for the note. Thus you can change between subtraction and addition and complete directly because the method is not coupled with the two signs or taking b = -1 has only a change in the latter here.$tan^{-1}(-1)$ Because I put the method in the general condition of the shape $\int\frac{1}{a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)}dx ,(a.b)\neq(0.0)$ Not for$\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}dx$

Comment: thank you Bachamohamed